# How to filter email originating from @domain.com on Exim4?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, exim, relay

I'm trying to implement a basic phishing protection on our Exim4 email relay.
The way we have our mail delivery setup is following:

external hosted smtp server -> exim4 relay -> Exchange server

Recently, we started to receive a lot of phishing emails with "from:administrator@domain.com"
I thought I'll implement a basic filter dropping all emails originating from @domain.com, because there is no legitimate way email originating from our domain could hit the exim relay, as all internal traffic is handled by the Exchange server.

I tried following:

```
reject_domains:
  driver = redirect
  domains = domain.com
  allow_fail
  data = :fail: Connection rejected: source $domain is manually blacklisted.
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all, I suspect it's because the "dropped" domain = local domain?

Thanks for any suggestions how to implement this correctly.

Comment: "dropping all emails originating from @domain.com, because there is no legitimate way email originating from our domain" You should instead look at standard technologies existing for those needs, which is SPF, and related DKIM/DMARC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I figured out another way how to do it by using

```
acl_check_data:
deny senders = /etc/deny_senders
```

and putting our domain name in that file.

Looks like it is working as supposed.

Comment: Interesting sharing, it would be better to mark this solution as answer tomorrow.